# What is the preferred way to upload images to S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am working on a web app that can take an image from a client, extract data using OCR, return the results to the client and store the results along with the image on the server.

problem:
I want to upload the file via a lambda function since I prefer this route for security reasons, but I have a hard time sending the file to the lambda using an API(not CORS-related). Now I am not sure if I am even doing it the right way.

JSON stringify reads the file object as empty {}.
error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()

question:
What is the best practice in cases like this?

extra info:
I was able to run tests with string data using the API, Lambda function, and dynamo DB. I have also set up the IAM roles and permissions between the services (S3 included).
I also tested my bucket using node js and CLI settings, which I did to make sure my syntax was correct.

Comment: "hard time sending" - it is not specific. Exactly what is happening? What is your lambda code? What errors do you get?

Comment: JSON stringify reads the file object as empty {}. error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: it never reached the lambda code

Comment: There are many ways to send a file to s3, most of which are acceptable. If you are sending it via a lambda function, I'd suggest first trying it out in the test console. What do you get when testing? Is it different than the results sent from your website? If so, that's a start. It's a good idea to host the lambda function and test locally as well, which can give you a little more valuable insight as to where your function is failing, as well as allowing you to set breakpoints to see the values of objects as they are being passed in.

Comment: thankyou, I will try that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I followed Brandon Miller's tip and found the err, I am now able to load up using pre-signed URLs, thanks!